# Image Blurs / Distorts When Moving in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

So I am moving this panda around the page with css changes in jquery (top, left positions), and it seems that as I move it, some of the time the edges aren't smooth. But when it stands still for a few seconds and then runs again (changing a gif each time) then it is fine.. Could someone explain why this is happening and any suggestions on how to fix it?

**Key Code:**

Changing the panda position:
         `$(this).css('left', $(this).offset().left`

Making the panda fall:
`$("#panda").css("top", $("#panda").offset().top + newpandatop);`

Moving the map:

```
theinterval = setInterval(function(){
                    $('#map').children().each(function(){
                        if($(this).attr("id") != "panda"){
                            eval(thecode);
                        }
                    });                               
                }, 20);
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: add your code here so we can help you better

Comment: I'm not very sure, but it may be because your top and left positions are not integer values, so lines are on "half pixels". Try `Math.floor(value)` instead of just `value`

Comment: First, GIFs are horrible for animation if you want clean lines. Transparent GIFs are binary for transparency - either the pixel is on or it is off. There is no alpha range. As such, you are almost assured to get a jagged edge using GIFs. Instead try using sprite animating aPNGs  if you want to keep things looking clean.

You second image is exactly what I would expect out of a GIF in animation.

Comment: But why do I get it nice and smooth sometimes and sometimes not? Can alpha channels use multiple images at once? What's the best way of making an image change to make it look like the panda is running? I have 6 image frames..

Comment: Once you move it, it breaks free of the pixels that were being used in frame 1 to fake antialiasing. By frame 2, the "transitional" pixels are gone and it is just your panda, non-aliased, moving on the screen.

The best method if you have transparency and a background you want to animate on and it is a simple animation like running - just use an aPNG sprite.

Comment: I'm looking up aPNGs now and it says my browser (chrome) does not support apngs?

Comment: Nice panda with eval code example, lol. Have a look at [this](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) article

Comment: use the  `requestAnimationFrame`  http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/

Comment: Yeh request animation frame reduced my code but still no luck!